# Solve $x^2+(8y)^2=p^2(4p^2y^2+1)$

Tags: diophantine-equations, pell-type-equations

I am trying to find solutions for $x^2+(8y)^2=p^2(4p^2y^2+1)$ for integer $x,y$ where $p$ is a prime $\equiv 1 \mod 4$ that does not divide $x,y$.

I think there are no solutions but I could not prove this. Obviously $x$ is odd, and $4p^2y^2+1$ is a product of primes $\equiv 1 \mod 4$, but I am unable to progress.

Note that the equation can be rearranged to the Pell-like equation
$$x^2-(p^4-16)(2y)^2=p^2$$

Comment: It seems to only have trivial sorts of solutions in $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$, which should do it.

Comment: @JohnSamples: Not sure if I get that but $1^2+32^2=1025 \equiv 0 \mod 5^2$ - isn't that a non-trivial solution? But this is modulo 25 and does not lead to a solution of the equation.

Comment: $8|(p^2-x^2) \implies 2|y$

Comment: For $p> 5,15|(p^4-16)\implies 240|(x^2-p^2)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try $p=5$, $x=691$, $y=14$. https://www.alpertron.com.ar/QUAD.HTM is a good resource.